# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop & commands could not be located

Tags: login, execute-command

after I powered my system on I was stuck on a login loop.
After I logged in by terminal many of the commands like 'ls, sudo, ...' didn't work and said:

```
the command could not be located because '<path of the command>' is not included in the PATH environment variable
```

this problem is solved when I do `source ~/.bashrc` and `source /etc/environment` but I still don't know how to login

Comment: `echo $PATH` just after terminal login. After `source`ing both files, `sudo journalctl -x --since="-20 minutes"` and read the messages

Comment: thx i found the problem. i made a mistake in my /etc/environment. it was  `ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=$HOME/Android/android-sdk  PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`.